# Demote from Production tract to Beta - Android

Tags: android, google-play, google-console-developer

I accidentally released my app to production even though it was supposed to be in beta. 
Quickly after realizing it, I ended up unpublishing the app.
How to demote it to beta channel?

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of issue you can contact Play console support. The support contact is on the help menu behind the "?" question mark icon.

Normally this is impossible but if you have no user installs they may be able to help you. But you should ask Play Console Support.